# manipulate objects from inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, chart.js

I have a problem and need some help.
I create charts with chart.js and i want to update them with a function.

I have the following setup:

```
function createchart(obj){
var kdChart = new Chart(kdchart, {
          type: 'line',
          data: data,
          options: options
        });
```

now i try to update the chart with a 2nd function like this:

```
function updatechart(){
  //collect new data...
  kdChart.data.labels = datepoints;
  kdChart.data.datasets[0].data = kdata;
  kdChart.data.datasets[1].data = ddata;
  kdChart.update();
}
```

Now i get error

> TypeError: kdChart.data is undefined

When i create the Chart outside the createchart-function it works.
What am I doing wrong here?
How can i update an object from inside a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your variable is only live within your function.  Do something like

```
function createchart(...) {
    var kdchart = ...
    ...
    return kdchart;
}
```

And when you call this function go stick kdchart somewhere where you can find it--on the window object is no where else

Comment: I think i got it... Thanks...
I have tried it here an it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/pfmd86/fcbcLbn3/

Comment: now i have another "but"...
I call the function to create the chart inside a success function of a ajax call... And i call more than one "create-chart" inside this function...

Comment: If there are multiple charts involved then create some object to store the charts.  If this answer has answered your question, then please accept it

Answer (score 0):

It is because of scope of variable kdChart is not global. It is live until execution is inside that function otherwise it is dead.

Either you can create it globally or create that object onside one function and return but you have to call that function everywhere you need that and not necessary that you will get same reference.

Create Global object so that it will have only one copy to access.

Comment: It's clear now. I called the variable outside the function and everything is working now!